# Property of atomless probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following claim:

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  be an atomless probability space. Then there exists a collection $\left\{ G_{t}\right\} _{t\in\left[0,1\right]}$
  such that $s\leq t\Longrightarrow G_{S}\subseteq G_{t}$
  and $\mu\left(G_{t}\right)=t$
  for all $t\in\left[0,1\right]$.
I already know that given $F\in\mathcal{F}$
 for every $\varepsilon\in\left(0,\mu\left(F\right)\right)$
  there exists $\mathcal{F}\ni G\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
  s.t $\mu\left(G\right)=\varepsilon$.
Finding sets with measures $t\in[0,1]$ is immediate from this, my problem is with making them nested like in the claim.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "proof sketch" given here (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is Theorem 2 from a [paper](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~vtroitsky/papers/math/done/real-partit/real-partit-en.pdf). He calls $\{ G_t \}$ a *real partition* and proves its existence for *complete* nonatomic probability measures using Zorn's Lemma.